# What is the correct way of structuring private methods that are going to be called inside a classmethod?

Tags: python, oop

What is the correct way of structuring private methods that are going to be called inside a classmethod? There is such a thing as a private classmethod?

```
class Foo:
    def _bar(self):
        # do something

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        cls._bar()


>> Foo.bar()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in bar
TypeError: unbound method _bar() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Comment: You need to pass it an instance. Also, if this is Python 2, you really should always be inheriting from `object` explicitly. Using old-style classes is... fraught with potential traps. Also, there is no relevance to "private" here. **Python doesn't have private methods/attributes**. There is only privacy by convention. You are simply trying to call an instance method incorrectly, i.e. by not using an instance. This screams [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so you should tell us exactly what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I asked `the correct way of structuring private methods that are going to be called inside a classmethod`. I want to define private methods in a class that are going to be called in a classmethod of the same class. When I mean a private method I mean in the sense of "being a method called only within the scope of the class" even though python don't enforce it.

Comment: Then why did you ask "is there such a thing as a private classmethod" when you know that *there is no such thing really as a private method to begin with*? In any case, I said *you must pass an instance to the method*. It is an *instance method* after all.

Comment: I asked that because I saw that concept before(https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/private_class_method) and I wanted to know if that is possible to implement in python.  About your IOW comment,  I understand it. I don't need you to point that out to me like I'm a dumb idiot.

Comment: If you understand that, then I don't understand your question. Are you simply asking if you can put a single-underscore in the definition of a method you are going to decorate with `@classmethod`??

Answer (score 1):

If you need a reference to the instance in a classmethod (I cannot see why you would?), just pass it as an argument:

```
class Foo:
    def _bar(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls, inst):
        cls._bar(inst)
```

But maybe `_bar` should actually be a [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) to be called in a `classmethod`?

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def _bar():
        pass

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        cls._bar()
```

As pointed out in the comments, Python does not have private methods, nor attributes.

Comment: A very strange `classmethod` indeed.

Answer (score -2):

You can use name mangling to create a private classmethod:

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def __bar(cls):
        print('__bar')

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        cls.__bar()
```